# Catkin not building packages in order

Tags: catkin-make, catkin, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have just had a really odd problem with catkin_make. I have been successfully building a workspace containing three packages, two with messages and another one with an executable.

So far, removing the build and devel folders and relaunching the command worked fine, but now for some reason the process crashes in the linking phase of the executable while the headers of the other packages are still being generated. This means that I have to relaunch the command several times, getting different errors that come and go as new code is generated each time until finally the executable gets linked successfully.

Any ideas what the problem might be?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/294016/catkin-not-building-packages-in-order/) by [jotator](https://answers.ros.org/users/34724/jotator/) on ROS Answers with karma: 60 on 2018-06-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to tell `CMake` which package requires which `targets` (i.e. generated files, like the message headers or a library) are requires by your target (i.e. executable/library). Do this using the `add_dependencies` call.
This is also described on the [`catkin` documentation on building messages](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/building_msgs.html)

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2018-06-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jotator](https://answers.ros.org/users/34724/jotator/) on 2018-06-13**:
Thank you so much! After reading the page you provided I went back to the tutorial and checked my own CMake file and, indeed, I wasn't specifying the dependency.